# UIView Animation not behaving properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a UIButton (size 100,100) with text and a colored background. When the button is pressed, I want the text to disappear immediately and the button to change size, animated, to 1000,1000. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:195/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:180/255.0f alpha:0.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                          delay:1.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                     [myButton setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)];

                     }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     SetupView * sv = [[SetupView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                     //[self presentViewController:sv animated:NO completion:nil];

                 }
 ];
```

Now, if I take out `setTitleColor`, the button expands just fine, but the text is still there (obviously). However, keeping `setTitleColor` in makes the button size 0,0 and then animates to 100,100. This also happens when I replace `setTitleColor` with `setTitle:@""`. I've also tried changing the text or color in the animation with the same result.

I feel like it's something obvious I've missed, but I can't seem to see it.

edit: If I don't run the animation and just do `setTitleColor` or `setTitle:@""` by themselves, the text disappears as expected and the button stays the same size.

Comment: instead of setbounds, try setFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the way you used UIKit to style your button, just modify the layer in the animation block, not the view.

```
 button.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(10,10,1)
```

Maybe it is even sufficient to use the view's `transform` property.

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(10,10)
```

NB 10 is just an arbitrary large value.

Comment: That did it! Somehow I didn't think of just interacting with the layer. Thanks!